# How to calculate the velocity of a bb propeled out of a barrel by a syringe?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile, ideal-gas

I'd like help breaking this scenario down into the different calculations I would need to perform.

Suppose I have a syringe with the plunger pulled back, and the other end of the syringe is attached to a barrel with a bb in it. The syringe's inner diameter is $2$ cm, and the syringe's inner length is $10$ cm.  The barrel is $20$ cm long, and $3$ mm inner diameter.  The bb weighs $.2$ grams, and has a $.3$ mm diameter.

[image: Syringe with plunger fully extended]

I press the plunger in at a constant rate of $20$ cm/second, which forces the air out of the syringe, and propels the bb out of the barrel.  How can I calculate the velocity of the bb?

Here is what I've figured out so far:

- The syringe at the beginning will have some volume of air
- Moving the plunger at a constant rate will start to move/compress the air in the syringe
- The air will flow from the higher pressure of the syringe to the lower pressure towards the open end of the barrel
- As the air moves out the barrel, it will accelerate the bb through the barrel
- I think this means that the pressure in the system will not be constant

I thought this might have something to do with laminar flow, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it to this.  At any given second, I was thinking I could calculate pressure using $$P = nRT/V$$

But then as time goes on, the bb will start to move, and I'm not sure how much, and as it moves, volume will change.  So I'd need to know how fast the bb is moving to figure out how far down the barrel it is so I could calculate volume.   It seems like a catch 22. Please help.